# How to write a function that deletes a node in a linked list?

Tags: c++, nodes

So I am trying to make a program where I would delete a node in a linked list by the use of a built-in function. I don't know how to do so yet, and I left my delete function blank.

Here is my current code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    char name[30];
    node* next;
};

void print(node* head)
{
    for (; head; head = head->next)
    {
        cout << head->name << endl;
    }
}

node* add(node* head)
{
    node* people = new node;
    people->next = NULL;
    cout << "name"<<endl;
    cin >> people->name;
    people->next = head;
    head = people;
    return head;    
}

node *delete(node *head)
{
    // still left empty
}

int main()
{
    node* head = NULL;
    unsigned short numbers = 0;
    cin >> numbers;
    cout << endl;
    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < numbers; i++)
    {
        head = add(head);
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "LIST : " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    print(head);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Define the specification first. For example, should the function delete all nodes in the list or only specific node(s)? If it should delete only specific node(s), how to specify the node(s) to delete?

Comment: What node should be delete? - first one, last one, a middle one ( you need to pass to function a pointer to the node )

Comment: only specific node(s) and i want to delete the node that i put in the input(the user input)

Comment: just user know where is the location of node